# How to create post with multiple categories as string [wordpress/php]

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a post with multiple cathegories in text. The problem is that when I execute my code. All the data of the post passes correctly except the category which stays empty.

```html
<?php

$categoryID = array("lens","promo");

$new_post = array(
    'post_title' => 'title123',
    'post_content' => 'test123',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_date' => $timeStamp,
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_category' => $categoryID //Here is what goes wrong
    );  

wp_insert_post($new_post);
?>
```

After this code the category isn't set for the newly created post.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

[removed the 'h' in category spelling, little mistake while rewriting code here. though in the real code there is no 'h']

Answer (score 0):

Your first var contains an extra letter:

```
$cathegoryID = array("lens","promo");
```

Remove the 'h' and it should work fine

Comment: true, I kind of rewrote the code wrong. Though in my real code there is no 'h'. modified the post. Thanks for info

Comment: What is 'post_category' actually expecting? Does it expect an ID or the name of the category? I am not really into Wordpress so idk exactly what it does and how it works

Comment: It can actually get both. It can be an array of category slugs, id's or names. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/#parameters

Comment: Hmm I see. I would say try it with the page ID's both as string and as int. It should work like your example. Actually weird that's not working

Comment: I finally figured it out. I read somewhere in the documentation the use of names was not applicable anymore. They didn't update the documentation on the link i sent

Answer (score -1):

You misspelled `$cathegoryID` instead of `$categoryID`

Comment: true, I kind of rewrote the code wrong. Though in my real code there is no 'h'. modified the post. Thanks for info